# Am I missing a dependency for MEAN.io?

Tags: mean.io

I reviewed Stack Overflow and did some Googling before posting.

I have a fresh installation of Win10. I installed Node.js(v8.12.0) and npm(v6.4.1). I followed the mean.io installation commands:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/linnovate/mean.git
$ cd mean
$ npm install && npm start
```

I received several error outputs (will post below). I then proceeded to http://mean.io/2017/10/31/getting-started-mean-io/ and realized I needed to install MongoDB. I used the following https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community I restarted my computer and I still have the same output:

```
> mean@0.0.0 start C:\Users\reese\mean
> concurrently -c 'yellow.bold,green.bold' -n 'SERVER,BUILD' 'nodemon server' 'ng build --watch'

['SERVER] 'nodemo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
['SERVER] operable program or batch file.
[BUILD'] 'server'' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[BUILD'] operable program or batch file.
[] 'n' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[] operable program or batch file.
[] 'build' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[] operable program or batch file.
[] build exited with code 1
[] n exited with code 1
[BUILD'] server' exited with code 1
['SERVER] nodemo exited with code 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mean@0.0.0 start: `concurrently -c 'yellow.bold,green.bold' -n 'SERVER,BUILD' 'nodemon server' 'ng build --watch'`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mean@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\reese\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10-02T01_13_58_380Z-debug.log
```

I can share the full debug.log if necessary.

EDIT: FULL LOG BELOW

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v8.12.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle mean@0.0.0~prestart: mean@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle mean@0.0.0~start: mean@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle mean@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle mean@0.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\reese\mean\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\reese\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\reese\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\;C:\Users\reese\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\reese\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle mean@0.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\reese\mean
10 silly lifecycle mean@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   'concurrently -c \'yellow.bold,green.bold\' -n \'SERVER,BUILD\' \'nodemon server\' \'ng build --watch\'' ]
11 silly lifecycle mean@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle mean@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: mean@0.0.0 start: `concurrently -c 'yellow.bold,green.bold' -n 'SERVER,BUILD' 'nodemon server' 'ng build --watch'`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid mean@0.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\reese\mean
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v8.12.0
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error mean@0.0.0 start: `concurrently -c 'yellow.bold,green.bold' -n 'SERVER,BUILD' 'nodemon server' 'ng build --watch'`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the mean@0.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: You need to use npm install -g to make sure nodemon is installed globally

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I went ahead and tried that, I'm still receiving the same error. I restarted as well just to be safe. No dice.

Comment: can you share the full log?

Comment: I've added it to the bottom :)

Comment: try manually starting the startup script and seeing the result. Might give you a better idea of what's going on

Comment: So this is where my noob shows fully....I'm not sure where the startup script is or what it's named.

Comment: I found it defined in package.json. I did the serve and build separately...the build script is the one failing. TS1144, TS1128, TS1005, TS1109, TS1128. I'll try browsing around for these errors individually. Thanks for your help Perry. Is there a way to upvote you or something?

Comment: Hey! No problem man, so glad you figured it out. You can press the up vote button on the comments I think but other than that I'm just happy you figured it out....always had the same issues starting with the mean stack. Let me know if you need any other help